# Is my understanding for group algebra correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $k$ be a commutative unital ring.

Consider $\mathbf{Alg}_k^{inv}$ the category of unital $k$-algebras whose multiplicative semigroup is a group. Then there is a forgetful functor 
$$U:\mathbf{Alg}_k^{inv}\to \mathbf{Grp}$$ that assigns each algebra its multiplicative group.
This functor has a right adjoint $$K:\mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{Alg}_k^{inv}$$ which assigns to each group its group algebra. One can see this by observing that the group homomorphism $G\to U(k[G])$ is initial in the comma category $G\to U(\mathbf{Alg}_k^{inv})$ and thus is a unit.

There is something wrong with it, because a $k$-representation of a group is supposed to be equivalent to a $k[G]$-module. But now it is weird as it corresponds to an algebra morphism $k[G]\to Aut_k(V)$. Please help me point out what is the correct way to understand group algebra.

**OK, I realized why this is wrong. But what is the right way to think about it? It the group algebra construction a left adjoint to some functor?**

Comment: Can you explain how you are viewing $Aut_k(V)$ as an algebra?

Comment: @JasonPolak As a subalgebra of $End_k(V)$.

Comment: You can't add automorphisms. $k[G]$ maps into the endomorphism algebra of $V$ which is precisely the information that gives you a $k[G]$-module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group algebra is a functor $\mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Alg}_K$  which is **left adjoint** to the "group of units" functor $\mathsf{Alg}_K \to \mathsf{Grp}$, $A \mapsto A^\times$. It is defined for **all** unital $K$-algebras. No non-trivial ring has the property that its underlying semigroup is a group, because $0$ is not invertible. If $V$ is some $K$-module, then a $K[G]$-module structure on $V$ (which restricts to the given $K$-module structure) corresponds to a $K$-algebra homomorphism $K[G] \to \mathrm{End}_K(V)$, hence (by adjunction) to a group homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}_K(V)$. So this is precisely a representation of $G$ on $V$.

Comment: Nice. Does the "group of units" functor also have aright adjoint? (I would guess something like the coordinate ring of the group seen as a discrete algebraic group, though that might require extra assumptions).

Comment: The "group of units" functor from unital $K$-algebras to groups has no right adjoint because it is not cocontinuous. In fact, $K$ is the initial $K$-algebra, but $K^\times$ is (usually...) not the initial group.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks.

Comment: Yea I said multiplicative semigroup is a group, it excludes $0$.

Comment: This means that you only consider division rings. But $K[G]$ is usually not a division ring.